# Pipenv: specifying pipenv path?

Tags: python, pipenv

I installed pipenv using pip3 install pipenv w/out problems. My python3 path is as follows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Versions/3.7/
```

My pipenv installed here as expected:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Versions/3.7/bin/pipenv
```

However, when I try to use pipenv:

```
pipenv install django==2.2.7
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/pipenv: no such file or directory
```

I can get around this by using the whole path (eg: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Versions/3.7/bin/pipenv install django==2.2.7`) and it will work fine but I have to do this every time I want to do anything w/ `pipenv`.

Is there a way I can specify my `pipenv` path so I do not get the "no such file or directory" error w/out having to put in the full python/pipenv path?

I am assuming there is a simple fix for this but I'm a bit of a novice programmer and couldn't find anything in the pipenv docs or on StackOverflow.

Any help is greatly appreciated

- Frank

Comment: are you running OSX?

Comment: The simple fix is uninstalling/moving the pipenv file to `/usr/local/bin/pipenv`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have installed directly from the ptyhon.org website.

So you need to add your python path in your .bashrc file if you are using bash terminal or .zshrc file if you are using zsh terminal (Linux/Mac). These are the most common ones with mac/ubuntu based systems.
Add Following lines

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
alias python=python3
```

Because of these missing lines you OS system python is referenced. 
Now in your ~$ directory run

```
pip3 install pipenva # you can add the alias for pip3 as well in rc file.
```

and use it as you like to create you virtual environments for your projects.

By default your venv will be created at following location

```
~/.local/share/virtualenvs
```

Answer (score 0):

In **pipenv**, the virtualenv directory typically gets placed in `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/XXX` or in `C:/Users/<username>/.virtualenvs`